# Associative search in rails with mongodb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, ruby-on-rails-4.2

i would like to perform a search in rails form with backend mongoDb, and in my model named employee data where first name, i need to search salary in another table, and i gave relation to employee data as " belongs to salary ".i tried a lot figure it out how to give association.

```
def self.search(search)

  any_of({firstname: /#{search}/i })

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no joins in mongodb, try doing something like this....

```
def self.search(search)
  salaries = Salary.any_of(field: /#{search}/i)
  any_of({firstname: /#{search}/i, salary_id: salaries.collect(&:id) })
end
```

But i would rather suggest to use Mongoid Search module. Install gem and add this line to your model

```
include Mongoid::Search
```

For more details, https://github.com/mauriciozaffari/mongoid_search

Comment: thanks for ur time, but it doesnt work for me, all i want is salary_amount from salary table, not first name.

Comment: SO all want is to search user based on his first name and get salary amount against searched records?

Comment: salary_id is stored in emplyoeee table

Comment: Emploee.search('xyz').collect{|e| {first_name: e.first_name, salary_amount: e.salary.amount} }

Comment: It will return array of hash containing employee salary amount and first name.

Comment: its works, thanks for the lead.. salaries = Salary.any_of(field: /#{search}/i)